# Fire a trait model when updating relation with sync

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im using a "history" trait on my Laravel application, to store changes on edited rows. But I have a problem that my relations on the model, is not firing the `Historyable` trait. I have tried adding the trait on the relation models, but still, no recorded changes to those related models.

For example in my `App\Game` model, I have this relation to genre:

```
public function genres(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
}
```

And in my `GameController`, for updating the genre relation I do this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Game $game)
{
    $game->genres()->sync($request->get('genre'));
}
```

The trait on `App\Game` is called `Historyable` and looks like this:

```
trait Historyable {

    /**
     * [bootHistoryable description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public static function bootHistoryable(){
         static::updated(function(Model $model){
            collect($model->getWantedChangedColums($model))->each(function ($change) use ($model) {
                $model->saveChange($change);
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * [save description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    protected function saveChange(ColumnChange $change){
        $this->history()->create([
            'changed_column' => $change->column,
            'changed_value_from' => $change->from,
            'changed_value_to' => $change->to,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * [getWantedChangedColums description]
     * @param  Model  $model [description]
     * @return [type]        [description]
     */
     protected function getWantedChangedColums(Model $model){
        return collect(
            array_diff(
                Arr::except($model->getChanges(), $this->ignoreHistoryColumns()),
                $original = $model->getOriginal()
            )
        )->map(function($change, $column) use ($original){
            return new ColumnChange($column, Arr::get($original, $column), $change);
        });
    }

    /**
     * [history description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function history(){
        return $this->morphMany(History::class, 'historyable')->latest();
    }

    /**
     * [ignoreHistoryColumns description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function ignoreHistoryColumns() {
        return [
            'updated_at',
            'password'
        ];
    }
    
}
```

How can I fire the `Historyable` trait?

Comment: there isn't a model involved here ... `sync` updates the pivot table via the relationship, not the models on either end

Comment: Aha alright. thanks @lagbox, that gave me some more insight

Comment: potentially you could use a custom model for the pivot but it would be history stored for that entity not the models on either side